How to write a macro for loop in lisp imitating a for loop in C or Java?
In lisp, I would like to write a macro for loop without using the loop function in lisp which imitates a for loop in C or Java. I’d like to achieve this with only the basic lisp syntax.

No loop? Use do then.

Stackoverflow is not thought to write code for you. Best if you have a real programming problem and can show us what you have tried so far. This also sounds like a homework question.

I suspect this is a homework question, so here's an answer which, if you understand it, you will probably have learnt something fairly significant about Lisp and programming in general.
(defmacro for ((var init while step) &body forms)
  (let ((<c> (make-symbol "C")))
    `((lambda (,<c>)
        (funcall ,<c> ,<c> ,init))
      (lambda (,<c> ,var)
        (when ,while
          ,@forms
          (funcall ,<c> ,<c> ,step))))))

Now
> (for (i 1 (< i 10) (1+ i))
  (print i))

1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
9 
nil

This is not the way looping constructs are written in CL.  It could be in Scheme.

loop and do and other iteration macros are typically expanded to primitive tagbody special forms.
If you want to write your own iteration macros it would be a good idea to look at how, e.g., loop is expanded in a Common Lisp implementation. Here is an expansion of a loop form in SBCL:
CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 '(loop for x from 1 to 10 do (print x)))
(BLOCK NIL
  (LET ((X 1))
    (DECLARE (IGNORABLE X)
             (TYPE (AND REAL NUMBER) X))
    (TAGBODY
     SB-LOOP::NEXT-LOOP
      (WHEN (> X '10) (GO SB-LOOP::END-LOOP))
      (PRINT X)
      (SB-LOOP::LOOP-DESETQ X (1+ X))
      (GO SB-LOOP::NEXT-LOOP)
     SB-LOOP::END-LOOP)))
T

Implementing a for Macro
This is interesting as an exercise in writing macros, but in actual code you should probably use preexisting iteration forms such as loop, do, or use a package such as iterate. These solutions are tested, reliable, and can easily do anything that a C-style for loop can do.
I am pretty confident that the implementation below is subtle enough that a teacher will not mistake it for the solution of a student who would ask this question in the first place, but that there is something to be learned here that might help the student along.
A basic implementation is pretty straightforward using tagbody, but you should probably also implement jump statements like break and continue if the goal is to emulate C-style for loops. This is a little bit tricky, and there are a few ways that you might approach it. Here is one solution. I make no guarantees that this implementation is optimal or bug-free; think of this as a starting point:
(defmacro for ((var init) loop-cond step &body body)
  (let ((loop-again (gensym "LOOP-AGAIN"))
        (loop-increment (gensym "LOOP-INCREMENT"))
        (loop-end (gensym "LOOP-END")))
    (labels ((expand (b)
               (cond ((null b) nil)
                     ((atom b)
                      (case b
                        ((break :break) `(go ,loop-end))
                        ((continue :continue) `(go ,loop-increment))
                        (otherwise b)))
                     ((eq (first b) 'for) b) ; do not expand inside of FOR forms
                     (t
                      (cons (expand (first b))
                            (expand (rest b)))))))
      (let ((body (expand body)))
        `(let ((,var ,init))
           (tagbody
              ,loop-again
              (when (not ,loop-cond) (go ,loop-end))
              ,@body
              ,loop-increment
              (setf ,var ,step)
              (go ,loop-again)
              ,loop-end))))))

Here a basic tagbody form is established. If the controlling expression is false then the loop is exited, otherwise the body of the for loop is executed, the loop variable is incremented, and control jumps to the beginning of the loop to start again.
In order to implement break and continue the body of the for loop is first expanded by walking that code, looking for occurrences of the symbols break or continue (or their keyword counterparts to follow the convention of the loop macro), and replacing those occurrences with go forms which jump to the appropriate tags within the tagbody form.
Note that Common Lisp has a break function intended for use in debugging. The above implementation would not allow use of this function in a for body since any occurrence of break is expanded to a go form. For demonstration purposes this is not important, but more robust code may choose to handle this possibility. One solution would be to accept only the keyword arguments :break and :continue. It may seem confusing to have both break and :break available for different purposes in a for body, so a better solution would probably be to rename these commands to something like break-for and continue-for.
The expansion of a for macro invocation produces code which contains go tags. If you have nested for forms you need to be careful that the control symbols break and continue are expanded within the right context. That is, if you casually expand all such symbols in the body of the for loop, then they will all expand to go forms which reference the outermost loop. To avoid this problem you need to suppress the expansion of for forms when walking the body of the for loop. The bodies of these inner for forms will then be expanded correctly when the inner for macro calls are expanded.
When a for macro form is evaluated it expands into something like this:
CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 '(for (x 0) (< x 10) (1+ x)
                          (when (evenp x) :continue)
                          (print x)))
(LET ((X 0))
  (TAGBODY
   #:LOOP-AGAIN404
    (WHEN (NOT (< X 10)) (GO #:LOOP-END406))
    (WHEN (EVENP X) (GO #:LOOP-INCREMENT405))
    (PRINT X)
   #:LOOP-INCREMENT405
    (SETF X (1+ X))
    (GO #:LOOP-AGAIN404)
   #:LOOP-END406))
T

Here are some example uses of this for macro:
CL-USER> (for (x 0) (< x 5) (1+ x) (print x))

0 
1 
2 
3 
4 
NIL

CL-USER> (for (x 1) (< x 16) (* 2 x) (print x))

1 
2 
4 
8 
NIL

CL-USER> (for (x 1) (< x 10) (+ 1 x)
           (when (evenp x) :continue)
           (print x))

1 
3 
5 
7 
9 
NIL

CL-USER> (for (x 1) (< x 10) (+ 1 x)
           (when (evenp x) :continue)
           (when (> x 5) :break)
           (print x))

1 
3 
5 
NIL

CL-USER> (for (x 0) (< x 10) (1+ x)
           (for (y 0) (< y 10) (1+ y)
             (when (evenp y) :continue)
             (format t "(~A, ~A) " x y))
           (terpri))
(0, 1) (0, 3) (0, 5) (0, 7) (0, 9) 
(1, 1) (1, 3) (1, 5) (1, 7) (1, 9) 
(2, 1) (2, 3) (2, 5) (2, 7) (2, 9) 
(3, 1) (3, 3) (3, 5) (3, 7) (3, 9) 
(4, 1) (4, 3) (4, 5) (4, 7) (4, 9) 
(5, 1) (5, 3) (5, 5) (5, 7) (5, 9) 
(6, 1) (6, 3) (6, 5) (6, 7) (6, 9) 
(7, 1) (7, 3) (7, 5) (7, 7) (7, 9) 
(8, 1) (8, 3) (8, 5) (8, 7) (8, 9) 
(9, 1) (9, 3) (9, 5) (9, 7) (9, 9) 
NIL

